# How to increment value in associative array in BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop, foreach

I have array:

```
declare -A server
server[172.16.170.1]='t1.com'
server[172.16.170.2]='t2.com'
server[172.16.170.3]='t3.com'
server[172.16.170.4]='t4.com'
server[172.16.170.5]='t5.com'
.....
```

I don't want to write every time, "t1,com,t2.com ..."
I want to increment it
Ok:

```
first=0
first=$(($first+1))
```

It is work for the first element.

```
first=0
first=$(($first+1))
declare -A server
server[172.16.170.1]='t$first.com'
server[172.16.170.2]='t$first.com'
server[172.16.170.3]='t$first.com'
server[172.16.170.4]='t$first.com'
server[172.16.170.5]='t$first.com'
.....
```

In output we will have:

```
server[172.16.170.1]=t1.com
server[172.16.170.2]=t1.com
server[172.16.170.3]=t1.com
server[172.16.170.4]=t1.com
server[172.16.170.5]=t1.com
.....
```

I know, that we should use loop, but if i have a lot of servers, how i should use loop "for" ? With all my array variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things missed out, use an arithmetic operator in `bash` as `$((..))` with the pre-increment operator! under *double-quotes*

```
first=0
declare -A server
server[172.16.170.1]="t$((++first)).com"
server[172.16.170.2]="t$((++first)).com"
server[172.16.170.3]="t$((++first)).com"
server[172.16.170.4]="t$((++first)).com"
server[172.16.170.5]="t$((++first)).com"
```

and for printing the associative array just use the `declare` built-in.

```
declare -p server
declare -A server='([172.16.170.1]="t1.com" [172.16.170.3]="t3.com" [172.16.170.2]="t2.com" [172.16.170.5]="t5.com" [172.16.170.4]="t4.com" )'
```

And the for-loop version of the same. This will work **ONLY** in *associative arrays* (with `declare -A array`)

```
count=0
for i in "${!server[@]}"; do 
    server["${i}"]="t$((++count)).com"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
declare -A server
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))
do
  server[172.16.170.$i]=t$i.com
done
```

Comment: not bad. but if i don't know, how many elements in my array ?

Comment: You need to tell me where the information is originally.  If you don't have it at all, we cannot do it.  Is the array filled with the correct keys already?  Then we can iterate over them and derive the values from them (at least it seems like this up to now).  (I just see that's what Inian has implemented.)

Comment: I have a lot of values.  I show you first five, and of course, we have different IP. not only 172.16.170.0/24, i have a 192.168.1.0/24 and others.

Comment: Yes, but where do you have it?  In what data structure can the bash look them up?